# Плагин для автопроставления локатора на элементах сайта

Tags: python-3.x, frontend, selenium-webdriver

Коллеги, Доброго!
Пишу автотесты в селениум. На сайте постоянно меняются локаторы разных элементов. Знает кто-нибудь плагин или модуль, чтобы добавлял локатор к элементам, по которому искать буду стабильно? Или в какую сторону копать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите пример кода вёрстки, что-бы можно было что-то точное посоветовать.

Answer (score -1):

Если не меняется иерархия в дереве тегов, то из такой ситуации можно выйти используя XPath. Но по хорошему видеть бы пример вашей ситуации, что-бы более однозначно ответить.